# How to ensure the value of spatial interpolation more than zero

Tags: r, automap, gstat

I am using the *automap* package to calculate spatial interpolation because I do not want to specify the nugget, sill, or range in the *krige* function in *gstat* package.

The value I want to do spatial interpolation is PM 2.5. Its value can not be smaller than zero. But I get a few negative value. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Kriging weights are not constrained to positive values, such as for instance inverse distance weights. Somewhat exotic kriging varieties have been developed to address this issue; you could for instance check CRAN package `compositions`, for composition data.